# USB Tethering - I have a ping to google, but browser can't open web sites

Tags: networking, internet

I use Blackberry Classic Tethering to connect to the internet, which works fine to a certain point.
I can ping google and download html-files with `wget`, but I can't open webpages with any browser (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, ...). They all tell me the connection timed out.

What can I do to diagnose this? I have the latest Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

try reading https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_tethering
also what information does **ip link** list, or **ifconfig** the usb tethering should list as a network device